# How to make a dynamic change of the position of the text in the button?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, text, position

I was experimenting with buttons and I was wondering if, depending on the size of the button, I can change the text display from the standard vertical to horizontal?

For example, I made a button that changes size (height and width) when pressed I wrapped the text inside it in a FittedBox and change its size depending on the size of the button `fontSize: maxWidth` gets a size equal to the width of the screen. This works when the button is larger in width or approximately equal to the height

[image]

But if the height of the button becomes several times larger than the width, it does not look very good

[image]

And I was wondering if I could somehow change the direction of the text to vertical when the height exceeds the width?

```
  child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                child: Text(
                  'TEXT',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: maxWidth),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: You could try to either use MediaQuery or a LayoutBuilder in this case, so that if it is smaller than what would you like to, then you render the text differently

Comment: Can you include more about (parent)widget tree

Comment: @CaioOliveira And how can I make the text display from top to bottom ? So that each letter is under each other